# How can I use pointers received from a function correctly? (in C)

Tags: c, string, pointers

I've written a function called `safecat` that adds one string (called `ct`) to the end of another string (called `s`).
The resulting new `s` is then returned.

In the main function my task is to check if my function worked the intended way, and if so, then print the result of my function `safecat`.

The problem I have is that when I assign the return value of `safecat` to another `char`-string (in this case `str`) in my main function, the stuff in `str` which comes from `ct` is just garbage.
I don't understand where the problem is, if I just do `printf("%s", safecat(s, ct));` I get the correct result.

Here you see my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *safecat(char *s, const char *ct);

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Twin";
    const char ct[] = "Peaks";
    char *str = safecat(s, ct);
    if(str == NULL){
        printf("Error in function!");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}

char *safecat(char *s, const char *ct){
    int i, k, j = 0;
    int max_count = strlen(s) + strlen(ct) + 1;
    for(i = strlen(s); i < max_count; i = i + sizeof(char)){
        *(s + i) = (char *) malloc((strlen(s) + strlen(ct) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if(!(s + i)){
            for(k = strlen(s) / sizeof(char); k < i; k++){
                free(*(s + k));
            }
            return NULL;
        }
        *(s + i) = *(ct + j);
        j++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

I think the error happens when I assign `safecat` to `str`.
When I print out `str` I get "`TwinP' a`" instead of "`TwinPeaks`".

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What does this statement  *(s + i) = (char *) malloc((strlen(s) + strlen(ct) + 1) * sizeof(char)); mean?

Comment: I am looking at your code and I have no idea what you are trying to do with these `mallocs` there.

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings. `*(s + i)` is not a pointer that you can assign from `malloc`. It is a simple `char`, hence *'=': 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'* and *'free': pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1*

Comment: You don't need a `malloc` and `free` for every `char` in the string, just one for the string as a whole.

Comment: @Tim Wagner  You cannot enlarge the original array s[] such a way. So the function is initially wrong.

Comment: From a first glance, it looks like a pool of undefined behaviour. I don't intend to dig deeper, as it is quite obfuscated. If you have arrays, use array notation for indexing and naming your variables with self-documenting names would also help.

Comment: And compiler warning are your friend. Enable all recommended and pay heed to them.

Comment: [don't cast the result of malloc()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the size of the array

```
char s[] = "Twin";
```

in the function using `malloc`.

And in any case this loop

```
for(i = strlen(s); i < max_count; i = i + sizeof(char)){
    *(s + i) = (char *) malloc((strlen(s) + strlen(ct) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if(!(s + i)){
        for(k = strlen(s) / sizeof(char); k < i; k++){
            free(*(s + k));
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    *(s + i) = *(ct + j);
    j++;
}
```

does not make sense.  For example the expression `*(s + i)` has type `char` instead of the type `char *`. And also it is not clear why a memory is allocated in each iteration of the loop.

A correct approach is to allocate dynamically a new array with the size equal to the sum of the sizes of the source arrays plus one and to copy the source arrays in the allocated array.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done. Also you should free the allocated memory when the array is not needed any more.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * safecat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);

    if (result != NULL)
    {
        char *p = result;

        while (*s1) *p++ = *s1++;
        do { *p++ = *s2; } while (*s2++);
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Twin";
    char ct[] = "Peaks";

    char *str = safecat(s, ct);

    if (str == NULL) 
    {
        puts("Error in function!");
        return 1;
    }

    puts(str);

    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
TwinPeaks
```

Of course you could use standard string functions `strcpy` and `strcat` instead of the loops that can be both written even in the return statement

```
return result == NULL ? result : strcat( strcpy( result, s1 ), s2 );
```

Comment: Why loop yourself rather than using `strcpy`?

Comment: @DarkFalcon Because it seems he wants to do it himself using loops.:)

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the new string to the old string you wind up putting in the null character after the initial P. What you need to do is as follows.

1. malloc a new buffer (ns) of the size of maxcount.
2. strcpy s into ns
3. strcpy ct into ns + strlen(s)

Note. If you are not allowed to used `strcpy()`, then write your own version as a function `safecpy()` in the a similar fashion to `safecat()`

4. return ns

Note that you would want to free ns sometime later in the program if you no longer need it.

Comment: Dunno why it is downvoted. Seem correct and useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you misunderstand the meaning of `malloc`.

You are using `malloc` as if it would make a new slot in or at the end of a string. `malloc(sizeX)`, however, reserves a new memory block with `sizeX` bytes somewhere in the memory (rather than at a particular position that you could determine). And the result of `malloc` is a pointer to a memory block, not a character.

So what you do with expression `*(s + i) = (char *) malloc((strlen(s) + strlen(ct) + 1) * sizeof(char));` is actually writing a pointer value (usually something obscure when viewed as characters) as value directly into string `s` at the position of `s`'s string terminating character;

For your `safecat`, first reserve memory for the new concatenated result string, then fill it up with your logic (I suppose this is a programming assignment and you are not allowed to use `strcpy`, right?

```cpp
int slen = strlen(s);
int ctlen = strlen(ct);
char *result = (char *) malloc((slen + ctlen + 1) * sizeof(char));
for (int i=0; i<slen; i++)
  result[i] = s[i];
for (int i=0; i < ctlen + 1 ; i++) // note "i < ctlen + 1" for considering string terminator of ct.
  result[i+slen] = ct[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who helped. It was a coding assignment and I was able to figure it out the next day.

The stuff I've written must have seemed to be very chaotic as I've just learned about pointers, and yes, I was not allowed to use 'strcat()' or 'strcpy()'.